# How does the PHP code execute even without closing the ?> PHP tag?

Tags: php

Following is the code I come to notice from a PHP file:

```
<?php

# Should log to the same directory as this file


$log   = KLogger::instance(dirname(__FILE__), KLogger::DEBUG);
$args1 = array('a' => array('b' => 'c'), 'd');
$args2 = NULL;

$log->logInfo('Info Test');
$log->logNotice('Notice Test');
$log->logWarn('Warn Test');
$log->logError('Error Test');
$log->logFatal('Fatal Test');
$log->logAlert('Alert Test');
$log->logCrit('Crit test');
$log->logEmerg('Emerg Test');

$log->logInfo('Testing passing an array or object', $args1);
$log->logWarn('Testing passing a NULL value', $args2);
```

You can notice that the closing PHP tag(`?>`) is not present there but still all the statements within code are working perfect. I'm not getting how this could be possible to execute the code without completion of PHP tag(`?>`). I researched but didn't get any satisfatory explanation. Can anyone guide me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://blog.rogeriopvl.com/archives/php-files-closing-the-php-tag-or-not/) will help you

Comment: I've no-doubt done less research than you, so forgive me if the following sounds stupid or insulting. Since the file only has php content in it - i.e no html, I don't see what would be so hard about deciding that if the input had finished (in this case the php file) while there was still an open php tag, then simply append a closing tag onto the end of the input.

Comment: ["*If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.*"](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: from - http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php - `If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closing tag exists to tell the interpretter that it should stop executing the text and just output it verbatim. Unlike XML, which requires openning and closing tags to match to be valid, the PHP interpretter simply uses the tags to delimit where execution should start and stop.

Just like a PHP file could have no opening tag - meaining that the entire contents would be output, no closing tag is necessary as once the end-of-file is reached execution ends.

Comment: And it considered a good practice to omit the closing tag to avoid whitespaces (characters, new lines and etc) to be outputted to the buffer and thus send as data preventing customization of headers.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't remember any other reason, sending headers earlier than the normal course may have far reaching consequences. Below are just a few of them that happened to come to my mind at the moment:

1. While current PHP releases may have output buffering on, the actual production servers you will be deploying your code on are far more important than any development or testing machines. And they do not always tend to follow latest PHP trends immediately.
2. By sending headers inadvertently, you might have introduced a security vulnerability: say, you are doing a redirection, but hence the headers are already sent, the redirection does not work and the rest of the page might be output, thus the visitor may see what she was not supposed to see. While this can be mitigated by using exit, you know the story, only if every one of us utilize good programming habits every time.
3. Even if letting the visitor stay in the wrong page does not have a security implication, by breaking a session behavior, or in some other ways I've encountered over years, the security and/or session cycle might have taken some sort of blow in the end.
4. If not security, you may have headaches over inexplicable functionality loss. Say, you are implementing some kind payment gateway, and redirect user to a specific URL after successful confirmation by the payment processor. If some kind of PHP error, even a warning, or an excess line ending happens, the payment may remain unprocessed and the user may still seem unbilled. This is also one of the reasons why needless redirection is evil and if redirection is to be used, it must be used with caution.
5. You may get "Page loading canceled" type of errors in Internet Explorer, even in the most recent versions. This is because an AJAX response/json include contains something that it shouldn't contain, because of the excess line endings in some PHP files, just as I've encountered a few days ago.
6. If you have some file downloads in your app, they can break too, because of this. And you may not notice it, even after years, since the specific breaking habit of a download depends on the server, the browser, the type and content of the file (and possibly some other factors I don't want to bore you with).

Bonus: a few gotchas (actually currently one) related to these 2 characters:

1. Even some well-known libraries may contain excess line endings after ?>. An example is Smarty, even the most recent versions of both 2.* and 3.* branch have this. So, as always, watch for third party code. Bonus in bonus: A regex for deleting needless PHP endings: replace (\s*\?>\s*)$ with empty text in all files that contain PHP code.

Comment: This answers why you should do it, not why omitting the end tag doesn't cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/basic-syntax.instruction-separation):

> The closing tag of a PHP block at the end of a file is optional, and in some cases omitting it is helpful when using include or require, so unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files, and you will still be able to add headers to the response later. It is also handy if you use output buffering, and would not like to see added unwanted whitespace at the end of the parts generated by the included files.